# branch.io link behavior different in two iphones

Tags: ios, deep-linking, applinks, branch.io

iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus, both iOS 9.3.2 downloaded the app from the store.

When we try to use a live branch link,

iPhone 6S: app store is opened
iPhone 6S Plus: app is opened

What are the possible problems here?

Comment: Maybe you should try long press click on the link and force app open? If app was opened from universal link and later user clicked website name in top right corner (prefer website over the app) opening website becomes the default behavior for the universal links for that website.

Answer (score 2):

Alex with Branch.io here: my first instinct is the same as MP23 — it sounds like Universal Links may be disabled on the iPhone 6S Plus. It's pretty easy to do, and not always obvious when it happens. Try pasting your test link into the default Notes app, and then long-pressing and selecting *Open in [app]*

Comment: we did what you said, and when it shows "Open with our app" it works all the time. But we can't tell that to users right? Is there a setting in the iphone that we could work with

Comment: Default behavior for Universal Links is to open the app. So if the links directs to website it means that user have seen the app and still wanted to go to the website. Then if at some moment user forces the link to open in app it should direct to the app with any future click on the link.

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is a (pretty irritating) limitation Apple has chosen to put on Universal Links, and currently there is no workaround. Best thing to do is cross fingers and hope that iOS 10 will change this.